# Multi countdown

Tags: javascript, storage, countdown

I have a web page where I entered a countdown code and it works well. However, I can only call it 1 time with the id in html.
Second or third time, it no longer works. How can I always use it? I would need it 3 or 4 times on the page. Thank you.
This is the code:

```
  var counter = null;

  window.onload = function() {
    initCounter();
  };

  function initCounter() {
    // get count from localStorage, or set to initial value of 1000
    count = getLocalStorage('count') || 1000;
    counter = setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second
  }

  function setLocalStorage(key, val) {
    if (window.localStorage) {
      window.localStorage.setItem(key, val);
    }

    return val;
  }

  function getLocalStorage(key) {
    return window.localStorage ? window.localStorage.getItem(key) : '';
  }

  function timer() {
    count = setLocalStorage('count', count - 1);
    if (count == -1) {
      clearInterval(counter);
      return;
    }

    var seconds = count % 60;
    var minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    minutes %= 60;
    hours %= 60;

    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = hours +  " ore "  + minutes +  " min "   + seconds +  "  sec"; // watch for spelling
  }
```

Comment: I guess because of you calling your timer just one time.
You can create a constant and pass it the setInterval id for trace or clear it.

Comment: the timer call only works the first time. How do I create the constant? I don't know javascript :(

Comment: It's not really easy to adapt your code into handling multiple instances, because it's tied to a single global variable (var counter) and it has a global side effect (.innerHTML = ...) - I'll post an elaborate answer on this

Answer (score 0):

You need to encapsulate the functionality in a way that can be called many times. It usually helps to think about the question "As a programmer, how I'd like to use this?"

Usually, it's a single function that takes some parameters and does something and/or returns something.

As an example... wouldn't it be nice if we had a function `startMyTimer(...)` that takes a timerId, and an element and sets up a timer that will update that element? We already have the signature:

```js
function startMyTimer(timerId, element) { ... }
```

And now you can build everything inside this function. JS allows declaring functions within functions, which helps with encapsulation, so copying from your code it would look like:

```js
function startMyTimer(timerId, element) {
  var count = getLocalStorage(timerId) || 1000;
  var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second

  function timer() {
    count = setLocalStorage(timerId, count - 1);
    if (count == -1) {
      clearInterval(counter);
      return;
    }

    var seconds = count % 60;
    var minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    minutes %= 60;
    hours %= 60;

    element.innerHTML = hours + " ore " + minutes + " min " + seconds + "  sec"; // watch for spelling
  }
}
```

Note that now `count` and `counter` are both private to the scope of `startMyTimer`, so only within this function (and any function inside this one, such as `function timer()`) will see these variables.

So if you want to do exactly what you did, you'd use this function as

```
window.onload = function() {
  startMyTimer('count', document.getElementById("timer"));
};
```

Again, this is just an example of a posible solution - Maybe you could pass in the element id instead of the element, or a timer duration, etc., and the best solution is the one that fits best your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works well!
One last question: how can I increase the time? It starts from about 16 minutes and I would like it to start from 3 hours.

Comment: When it finishes counting, it does not stop at 0. Always continue using negative numbers. How can I make it stop at 0?

Comment: Where do you set the initial value for count? In there you should be able to increase the starting time. For the issue of counting below negative numbers, I would change the `if (count == -1)` to `if (count < 0)` so it will always stop if the number is negative.